# How to use a training set combined with confidence level to classify the samples in a test set?

Tags: r, classification

I am using the package `randomForest`, to classify the samples in a test set, based on a given training set.

In the training set, each record has a confidence level (e.g., this dog is a golden retriever with the confidence of 85%).

My question is: the default use of `randomForest` (or other classification packages in R) is based on an assumption that each record has a confidence level of 100% (e.g. this dog is a golden retriever for sure). How can I make a prediction (or classification) based on a training set where the confidence level is not 100%. In this case, a record of low confidence level may have less influence on the prediction compared with a record of high confidence level.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicates instances by certainty. For example, if a dog is a golden retriever with the confidence of 85%, then duplicate this record by 85 times (expanded the existing training set). Then, using randomForest to create the classifier.